# My windows 10 virtual machine under Virtual Box lost internet connection

Tags: connection, virtual-machine, virtualbox

I have a computer with Windows 10 and a Virtual Machine (VBox) with a Windows 10 system that I use for work, I never had a problem since today : I launched it and didn't have any access to internet.
I didn't change anything since yesterday so I don't really understand what is happening.

[image: No internet]

[image: Ping]

I tried restarting the machine a few time but nothing changed, here's my configuration :

[image]

EDIT : I tried with differents interface type nothing worked

Answer (score 0):

It may depends on your network device configuration.
First of all you should set you first interface to NAT and enable the second one to HOST ONLY ADAPTER
At least this config is what works for me, if it doesn't work, it may depends on your interface network devices config, but i don't know how that works on windows.